# Bash - Convert MONGODB BSON to JSON

Tags: json, mongodb, bson

I have a shell command that calls a MongoDB command and produces a BSON output. I then want to parse that output with jq so I need to convert the BSON to JSON using jq's tojson.

```
echo "db._adminCommand({replSetGetStatus : 1})" | /path/to/mongo
```

How do I implement tojson is it as simple as doing this say:

```
echo "db._adminCommand({replSetGetStatus : 1})" | /path/to/mongo | jq '[.[]|tojson]'
```

I haven't put jq on my server yet as I have to prove it works before I can get it released.

When I try .[]|tojson in the online demo it doesn't work but I wasn't sure if this was a demo limitation?

*EDIT*

So I managed to get "jq" on a test server running mongodb and tried this:

```
echo "db._adminCommand({replSetGetStatus : 1})" | /path/to/mongo | ./jq '.members[] | {Server: .name, State: .stateStr}'
```

The error I received was this:

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 8
```

So it would appear that "jq" can not parse the data from replSetGetStatus.

In the mean time as I sit back scratching my head, waiting for the Change Management Death Squads to turn up, if anyone has some ideas they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've seen some programs floating around called `b2json` which convert BSON to JSON.

Comment: Thanks John, I really wanted to use "jq" as I have more chance of getting this past change management and on to the server. Plus it has lots of useful features.

Comment: Oh I see.  Well, you should install "jq" on a test machine or your desktop in a VM (what's that, Change Management doesn't like VMs?!).  You must have some dev/test environment which is not so locked down.  If not, time for a new job!

Comment: New job it is then ;-) I need a test machine with Mongodb running and building VM's takes time.

Comment: Spin up a VM at Amazon then... That only takes 5 minutes tops

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use bsondump utility coming with mongodb:

```
bsondump yourfile.bson | head
```

Comment: Convert BSON to JSON: `bsondump collection.bson --outFile=collection.json`

Comment: what if bson contains many documents ?

Answer (score 3):

Export your MongoDb DB to folder:

```
mongodump --host localhost --port 27017 --db mongo_db_name
```

Folder with files-collections will be created. Create bash script with code below:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a array00
array00=( $(ls -d $PWD/*.bson) )
for file in "${array00[@]}"; 
do 
bsondump $file --outFile=$file.json
done
```

Save this file as `run.sh` in the folder with *.bson files.
Mark file executable.
Run file.